# Fair Performance Comparison

Tags: cuda, gpu, intel, gpgpu

I am creating an implementation for an algorithm on CUDA, and measuring the performance gain when using the CUDA over CPU.

- **GPU**: [Tesla K20m](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2029/tesla-k20m) GK110 Kepler, 2496 CUDA cores @ 706MHz.
- **CPU**: Intel [Xeon E5-2609 V2 @ 2.50 GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/75787/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2609-v2-10M-Cache-2_50-GHz) (IvyBridge quad core without hyperthreading or turbo, 10MiB L3)

i am comparing multi thread CUDA vs single thread CPU.

so, based on above, is it fair to compare the computation time on those processors ?

Comment: Imho this is not really a programming question. Besides that: The comparison will never be fair if you just use a **single** thread on the CPU. If you can parallelize your code parallelize your CPU code too.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "fair". If by fair you mean money you invested in programmers, hardware and electric bill - I think no, it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's not fair to make this comparison.

1. Why are you handicapping the CPU with single-threaded execution?
2. Sometimes, different algorithms perform better on different hardware.
3. I'm assuming you've written the implementations. You are likely biased in favor of the GPU.
4. Why is the choice between these alternatives a real-life scenario for anyone?

and a bunch of other reasons.

Also, make sure you're using the right metric. Time/cost or time/power might be more relevant than just measuring time. Or it could be "fastest performance you could get on a single machine" etc.

Comment: CPU implementation should be multi-threaded and *vectorized*, and also use the best available compilers and libraries. Other potentially interesting metrics are: performance / energy (after all, energy is what you pay the utility for), performance / man hours of developer effort (for environments where employees are the major cost factor)

Comment: @njuffa. Excellent comment. The only answer to the question is what gives YOU the most value for money and that takes into account so many factors, that only you can answer it.

Comment: @Chiel: Not everything in life is about money. Not to mention the fact that performance / cost is one of the measures that are easier to "game" in various ways.

Comment: @einpoklum. Sorry, I did not mean it literally. I just meant to say that he should optimize it according to his boundary conditions.

Comment: the goal of comparision is to check whether GPU can outperform the CPU. i have three implementation Single Thread CPU, Multi-thread CPU, and Multi-thread GPU. and checking which one is doing better. since i need the comparison to be fair, i need the CPU and GPU comparable. i.e. it is not fair to compare the performance on brand new GPU with pentium 4 CPU. so my question is, are these hardwares comparable on performance wise not cost, not energy ?

Comment: CPUs and discrete GPUs are inherently uncomparable. Specifically, one is on the socket, with direct access to system memory, and the other is on a card, on the other side of a PCIe bus from memory. Not to mention your other choices which are rather arbitrary.

Answer (score -1):

I do believe you do have a very fair research question to answer, but I do share most of the concerns of @einpoklum but I do believe that **maybe your comparison can be fair**.

As a researcher scientist I asked myself this very same question a bunch of times before migrating to CUDA.

But, IMHO, yes, some comparison is fair for the listed hardware if you take in account some concerns:

1. **Reason for the comparison**: I do believe that hardware cost and running cost (investment depreciation and power) are the most interesting, because if you can write in CUDA it means you can use CPU clusters also, but, from my perspective it is cheaper to escalate on GPUs than CPU (i.e. a regular computer can handle multiple GPUs, while a mainboard to manage two processor is not that usual)
2. **Procedure objective**: it may sound obvious but it easy to overlook the code goal, since some procedures have too many dependencies by its own approach, while others are easier to wright in a parallel fashion (i.e. Monte Carlo simulations should perform better on a GPU than CPU, while if your goal is to solve mixed models, the very much opposite is true)
3. **Implementation**: as mentioned by @einpoklum, if you write the code, there is a great chance of your implementation to be biased, in this case, I would sugest to you to pick well widespread solutions for each approach (e.g. blas vs cublas);
4. **Your result will be restricted to the combination of the three points above**, so you should not be able to extrapolate the result to far. On the other hand, if the goal is to perform an exploratory research to solve or develop a solution to something new, it is acceptable to that makes use of something that already exist with mature implementations for GPU and CPU with similar goal and approach as a "model” in order to have a result to be extrapolated.

Just to be clear, I'm not a CUDA developer, but I'm working with it to solve some statistical equations and once I found a way to expose the parallel portion, the GPU approach presented itself as the best solution considering the user needs (i.e. fast solution with dedicated hardware)